# Has LEGO ever released a police/law enforcement-themed minidoll?

Tags: friends

Has LEGO ever released a set with a minidoll portraying a female in a law enforcement career role? I was able to, without much difficulty, modify a CITY police car to seat minidolls, but it is missing someone to drive around Heartlake City and bust drunk drivers and pet abusers.

I've looked at the now-discontinued DC Super Hero Girls (as the equivalent DC Super Heros line *has* included cop minifigures with some Batman sets), but didn't find anything. I also identified the LEGO Movie 2 figure Sweet Mayhem as an option,

[image: Sweet Mayhem] (Image credit: https://sg.carousell.com/p/po-lego-70830-lego-movie-2-sweet-mayhem-minifigure-doll-tlm116-210508801/ , no relationship)

but in reality she seems to be more of the military aviator type, and in any event does not have anything resembling a badge.

Comment: Olivia's mother Laura is a glaring omission in the reboot sets we've seen so far. I really hope they add a minidoll of her soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couldn't find specific police officer *digs*, but we can cobble one together until *LEGO* makes one, *cough*, official...

We're using the following two images as visual templates to see what we kinda want our finished product to look like.

Note: Police hat vs. Equestrian hat.  We can only choose one.

[image]

[image]

**The Part Recipe List:**

- [*Part# 92254pb01 - Mini Doll, Hair Combo, Hair with Hat, Long Ponytail, Side Bangs, Hole
  in Back with Black Horse Riding Helmet Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92254pb01&name=Mini%20Doll,%20Hair%20Combo,%20Hair%20with%20Hat,%20Long%20Ponytail,%20Side%20Bangs,%20Hole%20in%20Back%20with%20Black%20Horse%20Riding%20Helmet%20Pattern&category=%5BMini%20Doll,%20Hair%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# 15530pb01 - Minifigure, Headgear Hat, Police with Gold Badge (printed) Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15530pb01&idColor=63#T=S&C=63&O=%7B%22color%22:63,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# 36904 - Mini Doll, Head Friends with Sand Blue Eyes, Red Lips and Smirk
  Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=36904#T=S&C=90&O=%7B%22color%22:90,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# FTMpb003c01 - Torso Mini Doll Friends Bright Light Blue Polo Shirt with Dark Blue 
  Sailboat Pattern, Light Flesh Arms with Hands with Bright Light Blue 
  Short Sleeves Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=FTMpb003c01#T=S&C=90&O=%7B%22color%22:90,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# 61482 - Minifigure, Utensil Handcuffs.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61482&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Handcuffs&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# 3069bpb260 - Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Silver Police Badge with '2101' and ID Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb260&name=Tile%201%20x%202%20with%20Groove%20with%20Silver%20Police%20Badge%20with%20%272101%27%20and%20ID%20Pattern&category=%5BTile,%20Decorated%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part # 92253c00pb41 - Mini Doll Friends Hips and Trousers with Back Pockets with Sand Green
  Vertical Stripes and Light Flesh Feet Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92253c00pb41&name=Mini%20Doll%20Friends%20Hips%20and%20Trousers%20with%20Back%20Pockets%20with%20Sand%20Green%20Vertical%20Stripes%20and%20Light%20Flesh%20Feet%20Pattern&category=%5BMini%20Doll,%20Legs%20Assembly%5D#T=S&C=63&O=%7B%22color%22:63,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

  [image]
- [*Part# 92253c00pb05 - Mini Doll Friends Hips and Trousers with Back
  Pockets with Tan Shoes Pattern.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92253c00pb05#T=S&C=63&O=%7B%22color%22:63,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image: enter image descriptionhere]

Comment: Nice, I'd love to see the result of all parts together.

Comment: For the torso, the [pilot one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=FTMpb010c01&idColor=90#T=C&C=90) might work nicely too